# Removing resistor in Source Transformation method

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am trying to solve my simple circuit analysis question by using source transformation method. 
In the solution, my teacher removes 125 Ohm and 10 Ohm from the circuit. He says it will not affect the power but these resistors affect the total resistor. Or i misunderstood him...
Could you please help?

Edit : In the question i need to find Power taken by 250V and 8 Amper.

[image: Question]

Comment: You forgot to post the actual question being asked in the example. What were you asked to find in the problem. Click the "edit" link below your question ...

Comment: @Transistor I mean i want to understand that how we decide removing ineffective resistor. Did i forget something?

Comment: Yes. You forgot to add the actual question that you are trying to solve. If you were asked to work out what resistance the 250 V source is seeing then you couldn't remove the 125 Ω resistor. If you're trying to work out the current in the 20 Ω resistor then the 125 Ω resistor might be irrelevant.

Comment: @Transistor ah... Sorry. I edited the post. Question wants that find power taken by 250V source and 8 Amper current. How do we decide irrevelant or not, sir?

Comment: You can't remove the 125 Ω when working out how much power is drawn from the 250 V source.

Answer (score 1):

The power supplied by the 250V source is the product of its voltage (250V) and current. The current through it can be found by superposition.
With current source open, you do not care about 10\$\Omega\$ resistor and you can remove it. Calculate the current though the voltage source, call it \$I_1\$.
With voltage source shorted 125\$\Omega\$ doesn't matter so remove it, calculate the current though the voltage source again, call it \$I_2\$.
Total current should be \$I_1+I_2\$, and power supplied by voltage source is \$250(I_1+I_2)\$.
Follow a similar analysis for the current source.